# /opt partition not mounting in DD-WRT v24-sp2

Tags: networking, partition, dd-wrt

I'm facing problems trying to install optware packages on a TP-Link TL-WR841n v8 running DD-WRT v24-sp2 (4MB flash, 32MB RAM). I did the following through telnet:

```
nvram set jffs_mounted=1
nvram set enable_jffs2=1
nvram set sys_enable_jffs2=1
nvram set clean_jffs2=1
nvram set sys_clean_jffs2=1
nvram commit
reboot
```

And after rebooting:

```
mkdir /jffs/opt
mount -o bind /jffs/opt /opt
```

When I download and run optware-install-ddwrt.sh it gives me the following log:

```
Checking system config ...
Using 192.168.1.1 as default gateway.
Using the following nameserver(s):
nameserver 192.168.115.1
Warning: local nameserver is different than gateway!
Check config or enter:
sed -i s/192.168.*/192.168.1.1/ /tmp/resolv.conf
and try again - or wait to see if your download continues anyway.
Error: /opt partition not mounted.
for running Optware on JFFS (not recommended), Enter
    mkdir /jffs/opt
    mount -o bind /jffs/opt /opt
to correct this.
```

I had already entered **mkdir /jffs/opt** and **mount -o bind /jffs/opt /opt** but after that, in case it matters, **ls /jffs/** showed me nothing, and **/opt** does not show up anywhere after entering **df**. **jffs** and **opt** show up when I enter **ls /**.

Please mention anything important I could have missed. Could it be that the hardware specifications are not enough?

Comment: Strange: are you saying that `mkdir /jffs/opt` doesn't signal an error, but afterwards `ls /jffs/` does not list `opt`? What is the output of `cat /proc/mounts`?